# How to implement ASIHTTP Cache in my JSON Parsing application

Tags: iphone, ios

I am Parsing a JSON feed using JSON frame work. How to implement ASIHTTP Cache in my application . Means if there any new items , then only connect to internet and parse the new items .... otherwise display from the the Cache stored in the device ... how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Cache is available in ASIHTTPRequest only for GET requests.

```
[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
```

You can read all about it [here.](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). Scroll to the section: "Using a download cache"